# jquery .load() cant find index page with url parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I am using jquery `.load()` to perform an ajax call to my index file. This is also the same file I am already on. The only difference is I am adding some parameters into the ajax call. I have done this before with success, but this time I keep getting a file not found loaded into the div I am trying to place my retrieved content.

here is my js code

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
    var root = document.URL;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var url = '?name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&msg=' + message + '&submit=true';
    alert(url + ' #contact_response');
    $('#contact_response_wrapper').load(url + ' #contact_response', function (response) {
        $('#contact_response').html(response);
    });
});
```

The root variable I have been experimenting with but without success. I also never had to put `$('#contact_response').html(response);` in before either. Without this I cant even get a response. Any ideas on what could be my problem?

Comment: Do you have whitespaces in your message?

Comment: why is there a space before #contact_response
and something else, try to run url + ' #contact_response' from your browser. if it doesnt work, why should it work in an ajax request

Comment: that space is required

Comment: I have tried without the space for #contact_response but that did not help. Also my past successful calls had the space in it and failed w/out it.